# How do I implement the equivalent of hook_url_inbound_alter()?

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I'm working on a module which will resolve URLs to entities by altering inbound URLs so that if they contain an entity ID with following pattern "-{entity_id}" user will be redirected to correct URL.

A working example of the above:

Final URL:

- http://romajazz.it/concerti/pozzovio-de-angelis-4902
  Using the aliases:
- http://romajazz.it/concerti/-4902
- http://romajazz.it/concerti/i-can-type-anything-here-4902

I researched for a while; I found out there was `hook_url_inbound_alter()` in Drupal 7 which could solve this problem.

I also found that there is `InboundPathProcessorInterface` in Drupal 8.

I thought about implementing `InboundPathProcessorInterface` and use it in `EventSubscriberInterface` implementation which will subscribe on `KernelEvents::REQUEST`.

I wonder if this approach is correct. Are there any other ways of doing this in Drupal 8?

Comment: Have a look at \Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\EntityConverter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `PathProcessorAlias()` class is probably your best example.

- Create a module with a class the implements `InboundPathProcessorInterface`.
- Create the [service definition](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171) in your module.
- Make sure your service has the `path_processor_inbound` [service tag](https://www.drupal.org/node/2239393).  This will mark it for collection and tie it to the path processor.  You may need to play with the priority to change where it runs.

Your class will need to have some injected dependencies for looking up the entity.  `EntityManager()` got broken up recently, and I forget which ones you will really need.  You may also need/want the `PathValidator()` service.

Comment: Hi @MPD, thank you for your answer, it worked as I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concrete example of what code needs to be written so that when hitting a url such as :

www.my-website.com/my-pretty-alias

You actually display the content of the following page :

www.my-website.com/my-technical-needed-path/such-as/node/8

but my-pretty-alias is displayed in the url bar

In my_module.services.yml file :

```
services:
  my_module.my_service_identifier:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Service\MyServiceName
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound }
```

In my_module/src/Service/MyServiceName.php file :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Service;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyServiceName implements InboundPathProcessorInterface {

  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {

    if (strpos($path, '/my-pretty-alias') === 0) {
      $path = preg_replace('#^/my-pretty-alias#', '/my-technical-needed-path/such-as/node/8', $path);

    }
    return $path;
  }

}
```