# Multisite: Only Drupal Root recognized for subpath

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I am having a Drupal 8 multisite installation:

- Hostname: example.com
- 1st Drupal site: in example.com
- 2nd Drupal site: in example.com/sub/path

I have configured this in sites.php:

```
$sites['example.com.sub.path'] = 'subpath.example.com';
$sites['example.com'] = 'example.com';
```

The directories example.com and subpath.example.com contain the corresponding settings.php, setting.local.php, etc files.

Additionally, I have added this to the apache configuration (apache 2.4):

```
DocumentRoot /var/drupal
Alias /sub/path /var/drupal
Alias / /var/drupal
  <Directory /var/drupal/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Include /var/drupal/.htaccess
  </Directory>
```

The site example.com works as expected. 
I could install the site example.com/sub/path, but I now can just go to the home page. Every sub-page goes instead to the example.com configuration and gives an appropriate 404 error.

What did I do wrong/overlook?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: In https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223525/drupal-8-multi-sites-in-subdirectories-not-working?rq=1 they recommended to add a rewrite condition into the .htaccess file. This fixes the problem. However, I will have to patch .htaccess every time I upgrade Drupal core. Is there another way to do it, or is this the recommended solution?

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub/path/(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/path/index.php [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a rewrite rule into the .htaccess file fixes the problem. Without the rewrite rule for this path, the default rewrite rule goes into effect, pointing to the `example.com/index.php` instead of `example.com/sub/path/index.php`.

Disadvantage: I will have to patch .htaccess every time I upgrade Drupal core.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub/path/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/path/index.php [L,QSA]
```